# Converting JSON in url into a string

Tags: php, json, string, echo

http://api-public.addthis.com/url/shares.json?url=http://google.com

I need to get the number of shares as a php string. (echo)

Is there any simple way to do this?

Comment: `json_decode()` is what you are looking for

Comment: Here's one liner for you

`echo array_shift(json_decode(file_get_contents("http://api-public.addthis.com/url/shares.json?url=http://google.com"), true));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ret = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://api-public.addthis.com/url/shares.json?url=http://google.com'), true);
echo $ret['shares'];
```

Comment: Why does it outputs 1404114041 instead of 14041? Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry, it was this wrong part in my code. This answer works perfectly.